# Internet Explorer 9 - open address bar search in new tab?

Tags: tabs, internet-explorer-9

Does anyone know how to open address bar searches in new tabs in Internet Explorer 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter the address or search term into the address bar then press:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This will open the search results or the address in a new tab. It works in Internet Explorer 7, 8 and 9, Firefox and Google Chrome. In Opera it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can, but one pretty easy shortcut is to press ctrl, then quickly do T, then E. That opens a new tab then immediately puts you in the search bar, ready to type.
Once you get used to it, it's pretty fast.